# Any advice for crawling data from TripAdvisor

Tags: nlp, web-crawler, corpus

We are currently working on an NLP project and in need of a corpus that is intended to be extracted from tripadvisor.com. We are expecting the output as a couple of types: comment and the rating of that comment. My question is:

- Is there any crawling tool best for this purpose? It must be easy to use and python is preferred. Beautiful Soup is what I found but I wanted to ask it here for any other recommendations.
- Is there any complete tool just for this purpose? I mean a program that is written for tripadvisor.com?
- Any other recommendation regarding data(comment/rating) crawling from giant web-sites will be appreciated.

The corpus will be used in sentiment analysis for university research and we need to crawl it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For python you can use scrapy, that is a proficient crawler framework, http://scrapy.org/

In addition, I invite you to share the data collected by you. If the tripadvisor data is already ready, you wouldn't need to crawl. Or at least, you can share crawler scripts.

Comment: The data is not ready, but to be crawled as soon as possible. When the data is ready, I can share the data, but are you sure about scrapy? What you think about beautiful-soup? @Muatik

Comment: I think scrapy is more decent framework for the crawling web task. Beautiful-soap is not the same thing, not a crawler framework. Event though you don't use scrapy, beautiful-soup or something like these; you can still be able to crawl by fetching web page and then using just regex.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions in the respective order:

- What you need is a Web Scraping tool. A crawler automates the process
  of navigating through pages whereas a scraper converts the HTML in to
  structured data. There are many tools available in different
  platforms. No idea about Beautiful Soup. Are you designing the
  Scraper or will buy it?
- You can get ready made corpus or make a Web Scraper according to your
  customized needs. You can Request your Data or Write a Scraper
  manually using [ScraperWiki](https://scraperwiki.com/). I don't know the structure of your data but some data can be scraped using Google Spreadsheet. You can see that [here](http://vancouverdata.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-web-scraping-xpath-html-google.html). Just see what type of data is scraped and if it is analogous to your data then you can use it.
- Some sites or their particular directories cannot be crawled. You can
  check their `robots.txt` to know about the same. Also read the policy
  of the site before crawling data from it.

You have not asked but [here](http://www.fieldassignment.com/2011/04/free-sentiment-analysis-tools.html) are some free tools for sentiment analysis.